# jqGrid paging buttons work only on one click

Tags: jqgrid, paging

I'm using jqGrid in my project and ran into a strange paging issue. I can click on the next page button and go from page 1 to page 2, but any other paging buttons I push after that I get stuck on page 2 and can't go to other pages. I can however type in a page number, hit enter and then it will update the page displayed. I have pasted the jqGrid code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("#groupsTable").jqGrid({

  jsonReader: {
       root:"rows",
       page:"page",
       total:"total",
       records:"records",
       repeatitems:false,
       cell:"",
       id:"id",
       userdata:"userdata"
     },
  url:'project/selectTable/loadTableInfo.do',
  datatype:'json',
  colNames:['Name','Size', 'Number', 'Search','Delete'],
  colModel:[
  {name:'name',index:'name', width:500, sorttype:'text', searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}, 
  {name:'size',index:'size', sorttype:'int', width:150, searchoptions:{sopt:['le']}},
  {name:'mailList',index:'mailList',sorttype:'int', width:150, searchoptions:{sopt:['le']}},
  {name:'search',index:'search', stype:'select', width:60, sortable:false},
  {name:'delete',index:'delete',width:60, stype:'select', sortable:false}],
  pager:'#pager',
  loadonce:true,
  rowNum:50,
  rowList:[10,25,50,75,100,500],
  viewrecords:true,
  height:600,
  pgbuttons:true,
  pginput:true,
  loadComplete: function(){                
    var ids = jQuery("#groupsTable").getDataIDs(); 
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ 
      var cl = ids[i]; 
      X = "<span class='delete' onClick=deleteRow("+cl+");></span>"
      searching = "<span class='search' onClick=search("+cl+");></span>"
      jQuery("#groupsTable").setRowData(ids[i],{delete:X});
      jQuery("#groupsTable").setRowData(ids[i],{search:searching});
      }
    jQuery('#groupsTable').filterToolbar({searchOnEnter:false});
    jQuery('#groupsTable')[0].triggerToolbar();
  },
  caption:'General Info'
});
});
```

And the html:

```
<table id="groupsTable"></table> 
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: which version of jqgrid u r using?

Answer (score 0):

what i think you are implementing rowList in wrong manner, read the defination of rowList in this link

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid

or it could be a version problem also, check this link..

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/default-rowlist/

I hope it helps you

Comment: I'm looking at that, but I'm not sure what is being implemented in the wrong manner? What I gathered is that its an array of the number of rows you wish to display at a given time.