# Jqgrid page navigation through navigational arrows works only once

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an issue that is an exact replica of the one here

[jqGrid paging buttons work only on one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673042/jqgrid-paging-buttons-work-only-on-one-click/28409450#28409450)

My grid structure is also similar. I have set loadonce to true and I am changing the datatype to json on loadComplete.

The issue is that while navigating using the paging buttons, it works only once. But if I enter the page number through the textbox and press enter it works properly.

I am totally stumped on this issue. can you help me out?

Sriram

Comment: _I am changing the datatype to json on loadComplete_...why do you need to do this?

Comment: Since jqgrid changes the datatype to local after some local sorting/paging I am changing it back and reloading the grid. Removing this line does sort the problem out but my grid is no longer refreshed after editing a value and submitting. loadonce is set to true.so is reloadAfterSubmit

Comment: for that you can use aftersavefunc, oneditfunc. you can make use of it.

Comment: You are a real life saver mate!!!. I moved the code from loadComplete to afterSubmit and it works fine. Thank you. How do i mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am changing the datatype to json on loadComplete*. You don't need to have it. Instead you can make use of `aftersavefunc, oneditfunc` kind of callbacks if you have used.

As you have suggested you have `afterSubmit` then you can reload your grid there.